# Using CloudFormation to create Elastic Beanstalk "Hello, world." Java env/app

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

As far as I understand, when creating a Elastic Beanstalk environment, CloudFormation templates are created automatically to manage the env's resources. However---to avoid any confusion---this is not what I mean/want to do. I want to create the Elastic Beanstalk env/app *itself* using CloudFormation. There seems to be no example of this to be found. What would a CloudFormation template look like that creates the simplest possible, "Hello, world."-style Elastic Beanstalk env/app, as well as the accompanying Java code?

I'd be happy about any advice that guides me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four different CloudFormation resource types available for Elastic BeanStalk.

1) To create an [Elastic BeanStalk application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk.html)

2) Creates an [application version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-version.html), an iteration of deployable code, for an Elastic Beanstalk application

3) Creates a [configuration template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-beanstalk-configurationtemplate.html) for an Elastic Beanstalk application

4) Creates or updates an AWS [Elastic Beanstalk environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html)

**Note:-**

The above links doesn't directly provide samples to create "Hello world" EB application. However, I think you can use this information and create the application.

Comment: Thank you! I created this CF template: https://pastebin.com/z335Azdi Now, the question remains, what to put inside the Maven repo?

Comment: can you explain the utility of the "configuration template" resource relative to just the environment resource? Can it be reused and have only specific settings overwritten in the environment resource?